# time limit error exceeding due to modulo(10,9)+7 maybe?

Tags: java, optimization

There are N soldiers located on our X-AXIS. The point at which a soldier is located also has some number of bombs.
The war is near and every soldier wants to communicate with every other soldier.
If the `i-th` soldier has b number of bombs and is located at position X then the cost of communicating with any other soldier j having c number of bombs located at position Y is defined as `|X-Y|*max(b,c)`.
Find the sum of costs of communication if every soldier wants to communicate with every other soldier.
NOTE :- You have to consider pair(i,j) only once in sum of costs.

Input Format:

First line consists of number of test cases T. Each test case consists of three lines. The first line indicates the number of soldiers (N). The second line indicates the coordinates of the N soldiers ( X[i] ). The third line contains the number of bombs at every soldiers location ( B[i] ) . The x-coordinates needn't be in increasing order in the input.
Constraints

`1 <= T <= 20 1 <= N <= 200000 1 <= X[i] <= 1000000000 1 <= B[i] <= 10000`

Output Format:

The total cost modulo 10^9+7.
Sample Input

```
1
3  
1 3 6  
10 20 30
```

Sample Output

`280`

Explanation

there are 3 pairs (1,2) -> cost = abs(3-1) * 20 = 40 (1,3) -> cost = abs(1-6) * 30 = 150 (2,3) -> cost = abs(3-6) * 30 = 90 sum = 40 + 150 + 90 = 280

I'm handling modulo (10^9+7) and everything using brute force but getting tle code below its also working for the case above however it one of those annoying tle/type conversion type of problem. Any response is truly appreciated-

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int T=sc.nextInt();

    for(int ctr=0;ctr<T;ctr++)
    {
        int N=sc.nextInt();
        long [] x= new long[N];
        long [] b= new long[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            x[i]=sc.nextLong();

        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            b[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        int cost=0;
        double v;
        for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
            {
                v= x[i]%(Math.pow(10,9)+7)-x[j]%(Math.pow(10,9)+7);
                v=Math.abs(v)%(Math.pow(10,9)+7);
                cost+= v*Math.max(b[i],b[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cost);

    }
}   }
```

Comment: I suggest you emphasize more what the issue is, because it is not very clear and it kinda gets lost in the long description

Comment: 10^9+7 is a constant! It's just 1000000007L ! Don't calculate it 3 times for every loop iteration.

Comment: Formatting text

Comment: A clear case of using SO for competitive programming problems :)

Comment: Whatever you do, with 200k soldiers, there are 2e10 pairs, so brute-forcing makes no sense unless you could reduce the loop to just a few instructions. I guess, you need a much smarter algorithm.

Comment: @maaartinus even i think so cant seem to be able to do that sigh

Comment: Choose something simpler. For everyone, some problems are too hard ATM. I don't have a solution either. Problems like this one are fun, but possibly more math than programming.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Erwin, don't use `Math.pow()` to calculate `(10^9)+7` thrice in each iteration of the `for` loop. Instead, take it outside the loop (maybe define it as a constant) and then execute your operations.

Also, you are doing modulo with `(10^9)+7` constant twice in your operation. Are you sure that is the intended operation? You are doing it in the first computation of `v` and then again in the second computation of `v`. If you need it only for the final cost, you can remove it from the first step.

Here is my code that you can try:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double moduloNumber = (Math.pow(10,9)+7);
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Number of Test Cases (1 <= T <= 20): ");
    int T=sc.nextInt();

    for(int ctr=0;ctr<T;ctr++)
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Number of Soldiers (1 <= N <= 200000): ");
        int N=sc.nextInt();
        long [] x= new long[N];
        long [] b= new long[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Position of Soldier " + (i+1) + " (1 <= X[i] <= 1000000000): ");
            x[i]=sc.nextLong();

        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Number of Bombs with Soldier " + (i+1) + " (1 <= B[i] <= 10000): ");
            b[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        int cost=0;
        double v;
        for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
            {
                v=(x[i]-x[j]);
                v=Math.abs(v)%(moduloNumber);
                cost+= v*Math.max(b[i],b[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cost);

    }
}
}
```

I just added some print statements and moved the modulo constant outside the loop to reduce computation costs. You can check if this solves the purpose.

Regards,

AJ

Comment: Can you give me sample values that are giving you the error? I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Generally, in competitive programming, 10^9+7 is an edge case and if not handled properly, you will get TLE error. You need to reduce computation costs to not get the error.  

You are defining Array b as long but then taking integer as an input. If possible, you can define both Arrays x and b as integer and take only integer values. Also, try changing your cost variable to a double or convert everything to an integer as % of an integer will be an integer. Let me know if this works.